# Right way to close WPF GUI application: GetCurrentProcess().Kill(), Environment.Exit(0) or this.Shutdown()

Tags: c#, database, wpf, exception, close-application

My GUI desktop-based WPF 4.0 (C# .Net 4.0) program works with SQL Server database. Each time when I run my application it creates a connection to SQL Server via ADO.NET Entity Framework and if SQL Server is not reachable it throws an exception and shows `MessageBox` with notification.

Now I want that after user read this message application will shut down. I found three ways to do this:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

or

```
this.Shutdown(); // Application.Current.Shutdown()
```

or

```
System.Environment.Exit(0);
```

All of them work fine and do what I need — close application and kill application's process in Windows Task Manager.

My questions:

1. What is the difference between them?
2. Which way will close my application faster?
3. Which way to close application should I use?
4. Is `Application.Current.Shutdown()` and `this.Shutdown()` the same way to close application? Or maybe there is another, more suitable, way to close a WPF GUI application?

`Application.Exit()` doesn't work for me as I get the error:

> The event '`System.Windows.Application.Exit`' can only appear on the left-hand side of += or -=

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`Application.Current.Shutdown()` is the proper way to shutdown an application. Generally, because it fires the exit events, that you can handle, [further info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.shutdown).

`Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()` should be used when you want to kill the application as soon as possible, [further info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609795).

The nature of those methods is totally different:

- `Shutdown()` can be paused to end some operations
- `Kill()` forces the application to close immediately, as soon as possible

Probably, `Kill()` will be the fastest way, but this is something like kernel panic.

Comment: >> Ad4. That depend what this is.

I call connection function in App.cs constructor, so «this» — it's instance of App-class.

Comment: I use Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill() when the app can't find a data context (where everything is saved), and the user declines to tell the app where it is.  Since nothing can be saved anyway, the app just self-immolates.

Answer (score 2):

> Use  **Application.Current.Shutdown();**
>
> Add **ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose"** in **App.xaml**

Comment: For shutdown mode info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
private void ExitMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
```

Comment: you don't need to add anything to the App.xaml

Answer (score 1):

@Damian Leszczyński - Vash's answer pretty much covers the 4 specific questions you asked. For your final question on `Application.Exit()`, that's an event you can subscribe to, not a method that you can call. It should be used like this:

```
Application.Current.Exit += CurrentOnExit; 
//this.Exit += CurrentOnExit; would also work if you're in your main application class

...

private void CurrentOnExit(object sender, ExitEventArgs exitEventArgs)
{
    //do some final stuff here before the app shuts down
}
```